# Issue with tree table in IE8

Tags: css, vaadin, treetable

I'm using vaadin 7. I have an issue with tree table. Line between any two columns is missing. Please check the below link in IE8. I have a similar issue. Is this a bug? can be fixed?

http://demo.vaadin.com/book-examples/book/#component.treetable.components

[image: Missing column line in IE8]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is a bug.  Try the https://vaadin.com/forum